# Weird behaviour when inserting too many items to std::map or std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, vtk

I am working on point clouds and i use `std::map<int, std::vector<int>>` for down sampling the cloud. Keys in the map holds spatial index and vector holds ids of points. From this map i extract some points to process and that processing is done using multithreading(not the part with the map). At this point map is already out of scope. However, When my cloud is too big and downsampling ratio is too low i get a really strange behavior. Even though i use all my logical threads my cpu usage goes down to 60-70%. When i do the down sampling without the map(by simply skipping points) i don't get this issue. I checked that all the threads are running and my application has no mutexes they only read from the cloud which is a `vtkUnstructuredGrid` and thread safe for read only operation. I don't see why something like this would happen.

Could this issue be happening because of `map::max_size()` because when i decrease the size of the map i dont have any issue. Also why would it cause issue in my multithreaded part? My question would be does inserting elements to map more than `max_size` cause some sort of undefined behavior? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "strange behavior"?

Comment: You may consider to replace `std::map` with a sorted vector (if you really need it sorted). You may get a lot of cache misses due to memory fragmentation `std::map` has

Comment: my cpu usage goes down even though i use all cores and all threads are running

Comment: Without seeing the code, there isn't much we can give you.  It sounds like a thread contention issue but you say you don't have any shared state you are locking on.  It could also be UB.  It could also be a cache issue

Comment: @Slava i used a map to have points that are near each other to be close in the memory as well considering caching but that did not have any impact in terms of performance. Because normally cloud is unordered in the disk.

Comment: Maps don't put close objects to close to each other.  A map to could put the nodes **anywhere** in memory.  If you want locality, you a container like a vector.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica the area is voxelized so map indexes represent a voxel so each vector contains points from the same voxel. I though since map is ordered by key voxels will be near each other in the memory.

Comment: @AliKanat A map, particularly `std::map` is implemented as a RBTree.  That means it has nodes.  Those nodes get allocated on demand so every time you add an object, even though it gets linked in an ordered way, where that node was allocated in memory is up to the allocator.  They might be next to each other, the might be in "different ends" of the memory.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica ah i see thank you for that information. However, i believe that is not the cause of the problem, because in the method when i dont use the map i dont have any issue and that cloud is also not sorted in any terms.

Comment: Depending on how much memory is required to hold this data, it's possible that the system begins swapping which will mean CPU utilization drops as the system has nothing to do while waiting on disk I/O to swap in/out pages of memory.

Comment: @cdhowie normally i have free memory when this issue is happening but i am not sure if swapping happens